# Make a scaling/responsive image stick to bottom of div on/during resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a banner. In that banner is an image. When you resize the viewport/browsers width the image is scaled to a smaller size to fit the window.

Notice how when you resize the browser, as the image gets smaller, it moves in an upward motion away from the bottom of the div.

I want the bottom of the image to stick to the bottom of the div always. Regardless of size.

**Heres my [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/eaxe2sww/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <center>
 <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/">
 </div>
 </center>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  background:#777;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  display:block;
  }

.imgWrapper {
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:100px;
  }

.imgWrapper img {
  width:100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the bottom of the image to stick to the bottom of the div always. Regardless of size.

Add `position: relative` to the parent element and `position: absolute;` to the child element (along with `bottom` and `left` values).

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eaxe2sww/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for you https://jsfiddle.net/eaxe2sww/4/

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background:#777;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  display:block;
  }

.imgWrapper {
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  }
```